# Calculating AC-Coupled input current

Tags: clock, pll, sdr, capacitive-coupling

I'm using an SDR which uses and ADF4002-based PLL with its REFIN input [AC-coupled via a 0.1 uF capacitor to an external input](https://www.nuand.com/bladeRF-2.0-micro-REV1.4.pdf). I'd like to connect an external reference clock to it, but I'm unsure how to check whether the absolute maximum ratings of the ADF4002 would be exceeded.

From [the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adf4002.pdf), the ADF4002 has an absolute maximum REFIN input current of 100 uA, and has a DC-equivalent input resistance of 100 kΩ. My reference clock [puts out around 32 mA, which at 10 MHz is 13.3 dBm of power](http://www.leobodnar.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=234).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3fcVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How would I go about working out what current would flow through REFIN, and check whether the absolute maximum ratings would be exceeded?